# Change Schema Name in heroku ClearDB

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I just provisioned the clearDB add on, and received a random schema name.  Is it possible to change this name to something a little more manageable?

Answer (score 2):

I have asked the same question to the support of clearDB and they replied that this is unsupported for the multi tenant mode (Community tier) but is availble with the Single-tenant Basic or Pro systems.